# Python re.search

Tags: python, regex

I have a string variable containing

```
string = "123hello456world789"
```

string contain no spacess. I want to write a regex such that prints only words containing(a-z)
I tried a simple regex

```
pat = "([a-z]+){1,}"
match = re.search(pat, word, re.DEBUG)
```

match object contains only the word `Hello` and the word `World` is not matched.

When is used `re.findall()` I could get both `Hello` and `World`.

My question is why we can't do this with `re.search()`?

How do this with `re.search()`?

Comment: Because `hello` and `world` are not adjacent, but that is what your pattern is looking for.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with `re.search`?

Comment: In my original regex, i have around 4 groups. By,Using **re.findall** with groups, i couldn't get a complete match. Whereas using **re.search()**, i could complete match using **match.group()**

Comment: If you do not provide complete code to your problem, how can you expect it to be answered? Please ask a new question with your actual regex, and some sample input/expected output. This is the way to get a proper solution, otherwise, you will get nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will post a new question

Comment: Sorry @InbarRose . I deeply apologize for my mistake. I am new to posting questions. I have posted again clearly defining all problems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`re.search()` finds the pattern **once** in the string, [documenation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

> Scan through string looking for a location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string.

In order to match **every** occurrence, you need `re.findall()`, [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)', re.I)
>>> # using search we only get the first item.
>>> regex.search("123hello456world789").groups()
('hello',)
>>> # using findall we get every item.
>>> regex.findall("123hello456world789")
['hello', 'world']
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Due to [your duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20244228/1561176) ([as discussed at this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317353/1561176)) I have added my other answer here as well:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'([a-z][a-z-\']+[a-z])')
>>> regex.findall("HELLO W-O-R-L-D") # this has uppercase
[]  # there are no results here, because the string is uppercase
>>> regex.findall("HELLO W-O-R-L-D".lower()) # lets lowercase
['hello', 'w-o-r-l-d'] # now we have results
>>> regex.findall("123hello456world789")
['hello', 'world']
```

As you can see, the reason why you were failing on the first sample you provided is because of the uppercase, you can simply add the `re.IGNORECASE` flag, though you mentioned that matches should be lowercase only.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use `findall()` for some reason. That was the whole point of the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP also asked "why we can't do this with re.search()"

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough (not my post though)

Comment: @Peter: Right, sorry, busy with Inbar's question as well, so I didn't read far enough! :-P

Answer (score 2):

@InbarRose answer shows why re.search works that way, but if you want `match` objects rather than just the string outputs from `re.findall`, use `re.finditer`

```
>>> for match in re.finditer(pat, string):
...     print match.groups()
...
('hello',)
('world',)
>>>
```

Or alternatively if you wanted a `list`

```
>>> list(re.finditer(pat, string))
[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x022DB320>, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x022DB660>]
```

It's also generally a bad idea to use `string` as a variable name given that it's a common module.