# Python re.search() and re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-greedy

I am trying to solve this from problem from [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/t9-predictions). It is a Machine Learning problem. Initially, I tried to read all the words from the Corpus file for building unigram frequencies. According to this ML problem `word` is defined as

> Word is a sequence of characters containing only letters from `a` to `z` (lowercase only) and can contain hyphens (`-`) and apostrophe (`'`). Word should begin and end with lowercase letters only.

I wrote a regular expression in python like this:

```
pat = "[a-z]+( ['-]+[a-z]+ ){0,}"
```

I tried using both `re.search()` and `re.findall()`. I have problems in both.

- Problem with `re.findall()`:

  ```
  string = "HELLO W-O-R-L-D"
  ```

  output of `re.findall()`:

  ```
  [('Hello', ''), ('W', '-D')]
  ```

  I couldn't get the word `W-O-R-L-D`. While using `re.search()`, I was able to get it correctly
- Problem with `re.search()`:

  ```
  string = "123hello456world789"
  ```

  output of `re.search()`:

  ```
  'hello'
  ```

  In this case, when using `re.findall()`, I could get both `'hello'` and `'world'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [I posted on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20240276/1561176) you should use `re.findall()` - but regardless, your problem is that your regex is wrong. See the below example:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'([a-z][a-z-\']+[a-z])')
>>> regex.findall("HELLO W-O-R-L-D") # this has uppercase
[]  # there are no results here, because the string is uppercase
>>> regex.findall("HELLO W-O-R-L-D".lower()) # lets lowercase
['hello', 'w-o-r-l-d'] # now we have results
>>> regex.findall("123hello456world789")
['hello', 'world']
```

As you can see, the reason why you were failing on the first sample you provided is because of the uppercase, you can simply add the `re.IGNORECASE` flag, though you mentioned that matches should be lowercase only.

Comment: Thanks :) I could understand better now