# How do i search with re in a telnet session output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, telnetlib

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import re
import smtplib

print "Pasul 1"

HOST = "route-views.routeviews.org"
user = "rviews"
password = ""

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ", 5)
tn.write(user + "\r\n")

tn.read_until("Password: ", 5)
tn.write(password + "\r\n")

print tn.read_until(">", 10)
y = str(tn.write("show ip route 192.0.2.1"+"\r\n"))

print tn.read_until("free", 10)
tn.write("exit"+ "\r\n")

tn.close()

print "Pasul 2"

m = re.search('Last', y)
if m:
    print (m.group(0))
else:
    print False
```

Anything i search in the output it returns me False. Why? It should return the word.

This is the output:

Pasul 1

route-views>
show ip route 192.0.2.1

Routing entry for 192.0.2.1/32

Known via "bgp 6447", distance 20, metric 0

Tag 19214, type external

Last update from 208.74.64.40 4w0d ago

Routing Descriptor Blocks:

- 208.74.64.40, from 208.74.64.40, 4w0d ago

  Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1

  AS Hops 1

  Route tag 19214

  MPLS label: none

route-views>

Pasul 2

False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the string from the telnet session into `y` for this to work. Currently, you are storing `"show ip route 192.0.2.1\r\n"` in `y` due to this line:

`y = str(tn.write("show ip route 192.0.2.1"+"\r\n"))`

In order to do what you are intending, you must store the `tn.read_until("free", 10)` to be able to search it later. Currently, you are just printing it out.

Example replace:

```
print tn.read_until("free", 10)
```

with

```
y = tn.read_until("free", 10)
print y
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not searching on the full string. I'd need to see the content of `y` right before the search, but it looks like the value at the time of search is `show ip route 192.0.2.1\r\n`. Which would return `None`, as according to their docs [Python re.search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240239/python-re-search).

I think you can do something like `tn.read_until("$")` to read the entire session. Otherwise I would just concatenate all of the reads into a string and search on that. So in each read call

`y = "%s %s" % (y, tn.read_until('my_val', 5)`

Comment: so what should i do then?

Comment: can you please use it in the code and post it? i don't know for sure where you want me to add that, i'm sorry i'm a beginner and i'm struggling here :)