# What does the regex in this script's re.search() do?

Tags: python, regex

I hope someone could help me with this code, I am looking forward to use it.

```
# Absolute path of the script:
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Real path of the script:
REAL_DIR = re.search(r'(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])', 
                     subprocess.check_output('dir {} /al | findstr "<JUNCTION>" | findstr Ducati'.format(ROOT_DIR.replace("Ducati", "")), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('ASCII')).group()

# Absolute path of the sandbox
SANDBOX_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(REAL_DIR, '..', '..'))

# Simple FlashTool Path
FLASHTOOL_DIR = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(SANDBOX_DIR, 'DevelopmentEnvironmentPlatformTools', 'Tool.UDSFlashtool',
                'build', 'INSTALL', 'flashtool', 'bin', 'simple-flashtool.exe'))

# Network config file
CONF_DIR_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(FLASHTOOL_DIR, '..', '..', 'conf'))

# Log file path
LOG_ROOT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(ROOT_DIR))), 'tta_logs', 'FlashTool')
```

Especially this part

```
# Real path of the script:
REAL_DIR = re.search(r'(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])', 
                     subprocess.check_output('dir {} /al | findstr "<JUNCTION>" | findstr Ducati'.format(ROOT_DIR.replace("Ducati", "")), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('ASCII')).group()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20240276/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 okay thanks. Can you explain the above one?

Comment: From what I understand, it's finding folders (on a Windows OS) with the name Ducati in them, but what are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: To get the path of the script.

Comment: That's what the first line gives you. The absolute path is a "real path"

Comment: unfortunately it gives this 
```stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('ascii')).group()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programs\MAGNA Telemotive\tta\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Programs\MAGNA Telemotive\tta\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'dir C:\Users\Public\Documents\tta_workspace\tta_testcases\local\ /al | findstr "<JUNCTION>" | findstr Ducati' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: You can open up a cmd and run this yourself `dir C:\Users\Public\Documents\tta_workspace\tta_testcases\local\ /al | findstr "<JUNCTION>" | findstr Ducati`...

Comment: Sounds like you're asking what the `subprocess.check_output` does, now, not `re.search`

Comment: No, I'm asking about this 
```re.search(r'(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])'
```

Comment: Okay, well, in order to answer that, it'd be great if you could show the output of the above command because it's searching for content from it. And if that command throws an error, then the search isn't going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking specifically what the regex `re.search(r'(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])'` does, it's finding strings that are surrounded by square braces and capturing the content inside the braces.

- `(?<=\[)` is a positive lookbehind, asserting that before this match, there's a square opening brace `[`
- `(.*?)` is a capture group that selects any characters any number of times, but the `?` quantifier means it captures as few as possible. This means it won't usually capture the closing square brackets ahead of it; if you've got `a[s]df[ghj]kl`, it'll capture `s` and `ghj` instead of `s]df[ghj`.
- `(?=\])` is a positive lookahead, asserting that after this match, there's a square closing brace `]`

[See it in action here!](https://regex101.com/r/8JAads/1/)

I can sort of guess at the rest of the script, which looks like it's searching for symbolic links ("shortcuts") to something. The presence of `dir {} /al` makes me think this script is supposed to be run on Windows. `subprocess.check_output()` is going to run the command string inside of it, and then pipe its (possibly multiline) output to the regex, which is then going to use `.group()` to create a tuple of the matches it finds.